# database design for chat application

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, linq-to-entities

I have a task to do chat application like whats-app, but more simple

requirements:

-Chat between ONLY 2 users
-For every contact to get the last message(same like whatsapp).
-need to refresh each 10 seconds and gets the new messages only that received to he user.

I was thinking of design to make one-to-many between User and Messages
for Each Users there many Messages, and in Messages to save only the messages that related User sent

And one-to-many between User and Contacts(friends)
[image]
But the problem is that in loadMessages I will have to check two user tables and get relevant messages.

and also to update lastMessage to contact is problem.
What you think

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts are:

1:N means 1-to-many relationship

N:N means many-to-many relationship

User:

- ID
- Name
- 1:N Messages Sent (Sender Id on message)
- 1:N Messages Received (Recipient Id on message)

User Relationships (N:N Linking table)

- User1 Id
- User2 Id
- Relationship Type (i.e. friend)

Message:

- Message Id
- Sender Id
- Recipient Id
- Content
- Time Stamp

We can only put Receiver ID in here because you said the chat can only be between two people.

If you want multiple recipients you'll want to create a message recipients table with:

- Message Id
- Recipient Id

Then create as many rows of this as there are recipients for the message.

You could make it even more generic by creating a Message Parties table:

- Message Id
- Party Id
- Party Type (i.e. user)
- Party Role (i.e. sender, recipient, etc.)

Comment: But then every load messages for user will have to pass over all the messages table, this is performance issue

Comment: Hmmm... OK. Maybe make each live chat its own denormalized temp table, and when it ends persist to the "master" tables.